# Trigger javascript function when a button is disabled?

Tags: javascript, html, xhtml, onclick, disabled-input

If I am using a submit button as so..

```
<input type="image" name="submit" src="image.png" disabled="disabled" />
```

Is there any way I can trigger a Javascript alert when someone clicks this button? I have tried using `onclick()` but it doesn't work unless I take away the `disabled="disabled"`.

Comment: Whenever I need to do something like this, I create my own buttons using an `a` tag and then I can style them however I want (rather than using the disabled attribute I would just use a disabled class). I can handle the click with javascript and submit the form that way. It also means I get click event regardless of "disabled" or not

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the `disabled` setting also disables events.

If you need behavior to remain, then instead of disabling it, you should just keep it enabled, and enforce the behavior you want based on some flag added to the element, like a class or some other property on the element.

Comment: +1 you are correct, I didn't realize it used `stopPropagation()` so the event doesn't bubble up the DOM tree.